# Swapping and copying two strings into one another without using strcpy() in C

Tags: c, while-loop, c-strings, swap, function-definition

this program is meant to take two strings and call a function that copies string 1 into string2, and vice versa, while fulfilling the following criteria:

- Uses pointers
- Uses only while loops
- does not use strcpy();

This is what I have, but nothing shows up. How can I fix this?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void string_copier(char *a, char *b);

int main(){
    char string1[100], string2[100];
    
    /*read strings*/
    printf("Enter a string less than 100 characters.\n");
    gets(string1);
    //scanf("%s", &string1);
    printf("Enter another string less than 100 characters.\n");
    gets(string2);
    //scanf("%s", &string2);
    
    /*call function*/
    string_copier(string1, string2);
    
    /*print new strings*/
    printf("%s\n", string1);
    printf("%s\n", string2);
}

void string_copier(char *a, char *b){
    int i = 0;
    char *swap;

    /*assign string a to swap variable*/
    while(*(a + i) != '\0'){
        *(swap + i) = *(a + i);
        i++;
    } 
    *(swap + i) = '\0';
    
    /*redefine i to use in next while loop*/
    i = 0;
    
    /*assign b to a*/
    while(*(b + i) != '\0'){
        *(a + i) = *(b + i);
        i++;
    }
    *(a + i) = '\0';
    
    i = 0;
    
    /*assign swap to b*/
    while(*(swap + i) != '\0'){
        *(b + i) = *(swap + i);
        i++;
    }
    *(b + i) = '\0';
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `char *swap;` is just a pointer... you can't store any data in it....

Comment: @SupportUkraine I thought pointers are memory addresses to values, which can be accessed by dereferencing. Is this wrong?

Comment: A pointer must point to some memory. Your `swap` is just an **uninitialized** pointer so it doesn't point to valid memory. One thing you can do is `swap = malloc(100);` but you can also just make it an array like `char swap[100];`

Comment: That said... All you need is actually `char swap;` and then swap the characters one by one instead "copying" the whole string first...

Comment: @SupportUkraine ohh... you have to initialize the pointer, I see. Thanks

Comment: If you your professor teaches to use `gets`, find a better professor. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used or any link about gets you can find

Comment: Write your own `mystrcpy using only pointers and a while loop (3-4 lines of code). Then use `mystrcpy`.

Comment: [Or just do something like this](https://godbolt.org/z/dGv5cjYfn). Note that assumes what your code assumes: that both string bases refer to sufficient memory to hold the *longest* of the two strings. Ideally you ensure that by providing max-size arguments as well.

Comment: Logically you can not swap two arrays of different sizes without expanding the smaller one.  If your b > a, your code that does "assign b to a" should crash. Apologies if you are not looking for swapping "strings" of different sizes. PS: should this not be called `string_swapper`?

Comment: I applaud your attempt, but please consider ROI in your time.  (very) Many have tried to write "faster" string functions. Very few (if any) have succeeded. Take this as an "obvious" example of "slow" and try to beat it.  https://godbolt.org/z/W7ab1aqEb .  Using `https://github.com/sheredom/ubench.h `, ready for you to add your string swap. Benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead use either `fgets` or `scanf`.

The pointer `swap` is uninitialized and has an indeterminate value

```
char *swap;
```

So the following code within the function where the pointer is dereferenced invokes undefined behavior.

Also using expressions like this `*(a + i)` with the auxiliary variable `i` is the same as using the subscript operator `a[i]` that is the pointers themselves in the function are not increased. But according to the assignment you need to use only pointers to access elements of the passed strings.

The function can be defined for example the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void string_swap( char *s1, char *s2 )
{
    while ( *s1 && *s2 )
    {
        char c = *s1;
        *s1++ = *s2;
        *s2++ = c;
    }

    char c = *s1;
    *s1 = *s2;
    *s2 = c;

    if (*s1 != '\0')
    {
        while (*s1 != '\0')
        {
            *++s1 = *++s2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (*s2 != '\0')
        {
            *++s2 = *++s1;
        }
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    char s1[10] = "Hello";
    char s2[10] = "everybody";

    printf( "%zu: %s\n", strlen( s1 ), s1 );
    printf( "%zu: %s\n", strlen( s2 ), s2 );

    string_swap( s1, s2 );

    printf( "%zu: %s\n", strlen( s1 ), s1);
    printf( "%zu: %s\n", strlen( s2 ), s2 );

    string_swap( s1, s2 );

    printf( "%zu: %s\n", strlen( s1 ), s1 );
    printf( "%zu: %s\n", strlen( s2 ), s2 );
}
```

The program output is

```
5: Hello
9: everybody
9: everybody
5: Hello
5: Hello
9: everybody
```

As you can see the function itself does not use any C standard string function.

Comment: that works only if both strings are of the same length (not the `strlen`)

Comment: @ChefGladiator It is obvious that if you want to swap two strings then the arrays that store the strings must be large enough. The strings themselves can have different lengths. So your comment does not make sense. See this code snippet     if (*s1 != '\0')
    {
        while (*s1 != '\0')
        {
            *++s1 = *++s2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (*s2 != '\0')
        {
            *++s2 = *++s1;
        }
    } Moreover in the demonstration program these arrays contain strings of different lengths     char s1[10] = "Hello";
    char s2[10] = "everybody";

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/x3bYGseo8  -- one possible correct solution. You are swapping char arrays of the same size. string length is not what I am talking about. As I said in my previous comment. It seems your comment does not make sense :)

Comment: @ChefGladiator Sizes of arrays are not important except they have to store the swapped strings. The code in my answer does not swap arrays. It swaps strings. See the demonstration program in my answer. The function knows nothing about arrays that store strings.

Comment: @ChefGladiator As for your code then it is entirely wrong. See the function declaration in the question.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/of71Tj6z5 -- now please see your code failing :)

Comment: @ChefGladiator One more the presented by you example has nothing common with my code. The requirement of the function is the arrays that store string must be large enough to be able to swap the strings. Consider for example standard function strcpy. It is the task of the user of the function to guarantee that the destination array is large enough to store the source string. This is valid for all standard string functions. The same requirement is present for the function in the question.

Comment: @ChefGladiator As for your code then it is obvious that the second array is not large enough to store the string stored in the second array. So calling the function invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @ChefGladiator For example  in the section "7.23.1 String function conventions" of the C Standard there is written "If an array is accessed beyond the end of an object, the behavior is undefined" So it is the task of the user of such a function to guarantee that used arrays are large enough to store strings.

Comment: @ChefGladiator Consider for example one more standard function strcat. Again the user shall guarantee that the destination array is large enough to be able to store the appended string.